# How to convert QGIS 2.x composer templates to QGIS 3.x layouts templates?

Tags: qgis

The title says it all. I have a bunch of QGIS 2.x composer templates (.qpt) which I would like to use in QGIS 3.x.
I tried to create a layout from template, to add items from template and to copy/paste from QGIS 2.x composer to QGIS 3.x layout, but none succeed.

I had a look inside .qpt files and indeed they dramatically changed, according to the new QGIS 3 layout engine.

Will there be some kind of converter plugin ?

Comment: That sounds like it's worth making a feature request. https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here :
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-QGIS-3-layout-conversion-from-old-template-format-td5352994.html

1- Create composers from templates (.qpt) in QGIS 2.x

2- Save the project

3- Open the project in QGIS > 2.99

4- Save each layout (composer) as a layout template (.qpt)

This process is ok for a limited number of templates.